# Where can I find the Iowa Fluoride Study(IFS) data?

Tags: longitudinal

Anyone know where can I find the Iowa Fluoride Study data?

Comment: [Ask them directly](https://www.dentistry.uiowa.edu/preventive-study-contacts)? They seem to have published the data in 2009.